# How to optimize large data manipulation in parallel

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I'm developing a C/C++ application to manipulate large quantities of data in a generic way (aggregation/selection/transformation).
I'm using a AMD Phenom II X4 965 Black Edition, so with decent amount of different caches.

I've developed both ST and MT version of the functions to perform all the single operations and, not surprisingly, in the best case the MT version are 2x faster than the ST, even when using *4* cores.

Given I'm a fan of using 100% of available resources, I was pissed about the fact just 2x, I'd want 4x.
For this reason I've spent already quite a considerable amount of time with *-pg* and *valgrind*, using the cache simulator and callgraph. The program is working as expected and cores are sharing the input process data (i.e. operations to apply on data) and the cache misses are reported (as expected sic.) when the different threads load the data to be processed (millions of entities or *rows* if now you have an idea what I'm trying to do :-)  ).
Eventually I've used different compilers, g++ and clang++, with *-O3* both, and performance is identical.

My conclusion is that due to the large amount of data (GB of data) to process, given the fact the data has got to be loaded eventually in the CPU, this is *real* wait time.
Can I further improve my software? Have I hit a limit?

I'm using C/C++ on Linux x86-64, Ubuntu 11.10.
I'm all ears! :-)

Comment: Perhaps you are hitting some hardware limit, like e.g. the RAM bandwidth.

Comment: Are you sure your platform is capable of providing you 4x? Have you written any algorithm that gave you 4x performance over single threaded? Are all cores running at 50% duty cycle, or do you have 2 100%, and 2 idle?

Comment: Does hardware read ahead kick in?

Comment: This is what I was hoping for, hardware read ahead. How can I verify if/when this happens? But I'm afraid it already does.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of application is it? Could you show us some code?

As I commented, you might have reached some hardware limit like RAM bandwidth. If you did, no software trick could improve it.

You might investigate using MPI, OpenMP, or OpenCL (on GPUs) but without an idea of your application we cannot help.

If compiling with GCC and if you want to help the processor cache prefetching, consider using with care and parsimony [__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (but using it too much or badly would decrease performance).

Comment: I'm afraid I've reached the limits of my personal hardware. The application is a prototype in memory sort of relational DB, geared towards performace and parallism. As soon as I'll clarify this "issue" I'll post the source code under the GPL. I've been using in the past MPI and OpenCL, bur in this case the CPU itself is not the bottleneck I think, so GPU would not be so beneficial I think.

Comment: The wiser philosophy of free software is to show it during its development (the *release early, release often* motto), while it is still alpha and incomplete, to perhaps get useful comments or contributions... Publishing code with issues could provide you some help!

Comment: .I've tried a bit of preloading here and there but unfortunately doesn't appear to sort the desired effects. I'll try again a bit more, but is looking like more and more I've reached the limits of my hardware... Probably this is why for servers professionals buy CPU less fast but with a lot more cache?

Comment: I'd also suggest trying it in MPI (you can use OpenMPI on Linux), even if you're dealing with a single machine. It's also easier to code for compared to threading (mainly because there's no shared memory), so it's worth a shot.